# Control pattern availability is set to true but returns `Unsupported pattern.` exception

Tags: c#, ui-automation

Using [managed UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I'm trying to access the [SelectionItem control pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749016%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Chrome's [tab items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751611%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Using `Inspect.exe` I notice these `AutomationElement`'s have `IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable` set to **true**, which corresponds to [TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751611%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s documentation, stating that *"The tab item control must support SelectionItemPattern"*.

However, when I try retrieving the control pattern I get an `InvalidOperationException`, stating that the pattern is unsupported.

```
var select = tab.GetCurrentPattern( SelectionItemPattern.Pattern );
```

**Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply a mistake in Chrome's provider implementation?**

I also tried calling [`GetSupportedPatterns()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.getsupportedpatterns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns an empty collection.

Comment: Given that this seems to work for other applications, I presume Chrome's implementation is simply incorrect ...

Comment: Related issue [on the Chromium Accessibility group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-accessibility/ZSckMJnKABU).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this somehow? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Guillermo No, I ended up using another approach (writing a Chrome plugin to access the desired information).